# storing pixel ie rgb in double dimension array

Tags: java, rgb

i want to return the pixels to calling function but only last value is getin that means it overrides the value...

get_pixel_info() method is calling getPixelData(), in getPixelData() method values of 1st pixel r g b is storing in rgb[] array and returns rgb be back to calling function, due to for loop again control foes to getPixelData() method and this time override values of 2nd pixels on 1st pixel, and so on.. i want all values of all pixels, butim geting only 1

the values of pixels rgb should be returned to calling function pls help

```
public static int[] get_pixel_info() 
{
    int[] rgb={0};
    int[][] rgb2 = new int[0][0];

    BufferedImage img;
    try 
    {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File(IMG));
        int[][] pixelData = new int[img.getHeight() * img.getWidth()][3];
        int counter = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < img.getWidth(); i++) 
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < img.getHeight(); j++) 
            {
                rgb = getPixelData(img, i, j);

                for(int k = 0; k < rgb.length; k++) 
                {
                    pixelData[counter][k] = rgb[k];
                }

                counter++;                
            }            
        }
    } 
   catch (IOException e) 
   {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
    return rgb;
}

public static int[] getPixelData(BufferedImage img, int x, int y) 
 {
    int argb = img.getRGB(x, y);   
    int rgb[] = new int[] {            
        ((argb >> 16) & 0xff), //red             
        (argb >> 8) & 0xff, //green
        (argb ) & 0xff //blue
    };

    System.out.println("rgb: " + Integer.toBinaryString(rgb[0]) + " " +        Integer.toBinaryString(rgb[1]) + " " + Integer.toBinaryString(rgb[2]));

    return rgb;
}
```

Comment: 1.  please format your code 2.  please ask a coherent question

Comment: i m asking to return a value which contains the whole rgb values, i tried in above code but it returns only last three values, from which i conclude that in getPixelData() method values are overwriting.

Comment: so, 1. please format your code, 2.  describe exactly what your code is supposed to do, and what it's doing instead, _in the question_.

Comment: get_pixel_info() method is calling getPixelData(), in getPixelData() method values of 1st pixel r g b is storing in rgb[] array and returns rgb be back to calling function, due to for loop again control foes to getPixelData() method and this time override values of 2nd pixels on 1st pixel, and so on..
i want all values of all pixels, butim geting only 1

Comment: **I do not understand what you *want* to do!** So I cannot help you. Try to rephrase and improve your question.

Comment: this above code is for retrieving image information, ie pixels. i want to collect all pixel in an array so that it can be used by other classes. The above code is returning only one pixel information. array rgb[] cantains only 1 pixel information

Comment: Is your image valid? Try printing out the width and height of your image...

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean to use:

```
            pixelData[counter] = getPixelData(img, i, j);
```

instead of the third nested loop (`k`)?

Note, however, that your "conversion" actually offers little beenfit, except that it uses significantly more memory than the `BufferedImage` representation.

Comment: no,i want to make an double dimension array in which all values stores rite now only 3values are storing  Current o/p  149, 156, 138
required o/p   149,15,138     126,189,44    123,56,22.... and so on

Answer (score 1):

Take a good look at your code, and especially to the variable you are returning. You are returning rgb. You are NOT using rgb2 or PixelData

And while you're at it. Take a look at naming conventions in Java. Variables should not start with a capital and names should use camel-casing instead of underscores

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
public static int[] getPixelData(BufferedImage img, int x, int y) {
    int argb = img.getRGB(x, y);
    int rgb[] = new int[3];
    rgb[2] = argb & 0xff;         // b
    rgb[1] = (argb >> 8) & 0xff;  // g
    rgb[0] = (argb >> 16) & 0xff; // r
    return rgb;
}
```

Comment: ya it works, but it is sending only one value of pixel ie r g b at a time to the calling function,but i want to return all values of all pixel in singe step